# Prove that if $a$ is an element of a group with order $m$, then $m$ is the smallest such number that $a^m=e$.

Tags: group-theory

Let $a$ be an element of a group $G$ such that $a$ has order $m$ (i.e. the subgroup generated by $a$ has order $m$).

Prove that $m$ is the smallest positive integer such that $a^m=e$.

I'm not quite sure how to go through this one.  I tried contradiction.

I started off by saying that since $H$ is the cyclic subgroup of $G$ generated by $a$, then $H=\{e,a^1,a^2,...,a^{m-1}\}$. Now assume by contradiction that $m$ isn't the smallest integer such that $a^m=e$.  Then because $a$ generates everything in $H$,  there must be an $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ and $q\in\mathbb{Z}$ where $n < m$ such that $a^{nq}=a^m$.

This is as far as I get.  I can't for the life of me figure out how to get $n>m$ for my contradiction.

Comment: What is the definition of the order of a group element?

Comment: @Gage: It seems the definition the OP is working with is that $\langle a \rangle$ has order $m$ (this is stated in the first line).

Comment: Thanks @BrandonCarter I missed that. OP if $\vert \langle a \rangle \vert = m $ then are all the elements you list in $H$ distinct?

Comment: Yes they are distinct.

Comment: So if they are all distinct can $a^i = e$ for some $a^i$ in $\{ a^1, \ldots , a^{m-1} \}$?

Comment: Yes, you can say that. Where is that leading though?

Comment: Showing that $a^i \not = e$ for any $i$ less than $m$ because if it did then $\langle a \rangle$ wouldn't have order $m$.

Comment: Suppose thought that I don't know that for _H={e,a^1,a^2,...,a^(m-1)_} all the elements are distinct and I need to prove that. How would I go about proving it?

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts of this proof, the relativly easy part of showing that $a^m = e$ and showing that it if $i < m$ then $a^i \not = e$.

For the second part of the problem suppose that $a \in G$ has order $m$ then by definition we have that $H = \langle a \rangle = \{ e, a^1, \ldots , a^{m-1} \}$ is of order $m$. Therefore we must have each element is distinct from each other in the list $e, a^1, \ldots , a^{m-1}$ (since we can easily count that there are $m$ elements in the list). Therefore specifically we have that $a^i \not = e$ for $1 \leq i \leq m-1$ because if it did for some $i$ then $H$ would not have $m$ distinct elements.

If you then fill in a proof that $a^m = e$ then you will have completed the proof.